401 unauthorized Error in LTI 1.3 authentication flow with laravel
I am implementing LTI 1.3 using the LTI 1.3 library https://github.com/celtic-project/LTI-PHP, in a Laravel framework. The part of the flow that I need to perform using LTI 1.3 is an authentication flow from the tool consumer to the tool provider.
The code I am using to implement the connection flow is as follows:
public function ltiMessage(Request $request) { $tool = LtiTool::getLtiTool(); $tool->handleRequest();
When I execute the code, I observe the following headers during the login process:
_token:Iw4ElYfGOq7E6tJHz1BoSoCd5OzbzYNEpPoSi6GW
iss:https://urlPagina.com
target_link_uri:https://urlPagina.com/mod/lti/token.php
login_hint:1
client_id:1023970218937
lti_deployment_id:1
At the moment of redirecting the token request using a POST method:
client_id:1023970218937
login_hint:1
nonce:wdBEoJqRrq04pQ5egxpOce7qjoTjugcZ
prompt:none
redirect_uri:http://127.0.0.1:8000/lti
response_mode:form_post
response_type:id_token
scope:openid
state:GVtO3kqQ
repost:true
After following these steps as indicated by IMS Global, I encounter a 401 status, which prevents me from retrieving the identification token necessary to complete the authentication flow."
